# Loop Through and Hide Elements Containing a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I apologise for my ignorance - I'm very new to programming.

I'm attempting to create a script which will loop through `label` elements and then hide the parent `li` element if the `label` text contains a specific string. Please see my code below:

```js
var labelclass = jQuery("li label");

for (i = 0; i < labelclass.length; i++) {
  if ((labelclass).text().indexOf("Hide") >= 0) {
    jQuery(this).closest("li").css("display", "none");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
  <li><label>Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how far off I am here, but I think I could possibly be mis-using `this`. The loop could also be incorrect. Could anybody please provide any insight so that I know where to go next with this? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a loop here, you can simply use the `:contains` selector with `parent()` to get the `li`, then `hide()` it. Try this:

```js
$("li label:contains('Hide')").parent().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
  <li><label>Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
</ul>
```

The caveat with this is that `:contains` will match any portion of the content, so 'Do Not Hide' would be hidden too. To get an exact match you could instead use `filter()`:

```js
$("li label").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'Hide';
}).parent().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
  <li><label>Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Do Not Hide</label></li>
  <li><label>Show</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, you're quick! Thank you for this answer. In the back of my head I recall having heard heard some bad things about using `contains` and I think that stuck. This was far more simple than I had realised. I'll tick your answer when it allows me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by combining `:has` and `:contains` selector,

```js
jQuery("li:has(label:contains('Hide'))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><label>Show</label></li>
<li><label>Hide</label></li>
<li><label>Hide</label></li>
<li><label>Show</label></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.